# Linear Algebra transformation of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is like 
s: P1(C)-->C3
s(p(x))=(p(0),p(-1),p(1))
respect to basis `1,1-x` for P1
and basis `(1 0 0), (0 1 0), (0 0 1)`
I try to sub in first basis to the transformation.
so it is s(p(1)) and s(p(1-x))
but i dont know how to do the rest.
does p(0)=0 p(-1)=-1 and p(1)=1 for s(p(1))
and for s(p(1-x)) i couldn't find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the function $s$ once $p_1(x)=1$ and then $p_2(x)=1-x$. E.g.
$$s(p_1(x))\ =\ (p_1(0),p_1(-1),p_1(1))\ =\ (1,1,1)\,.$$

> And the matrix is: $\ \pmatrix{1&1\\1&2\\1&0}$.

Comment: Than you I think I get it. :)